# setTimeout doesn't work JavaScript "style undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fade in 4 div boxes, one by one. 
In css they have the opacity = 0.

Here my JavaScript code:

```
function fadeIn() {
    var box = new Array(
        document.getElementById('skill1'),
        document.getElementById('skill2'),
        document.getElementById('skill3'),
        document.getElementById('skill4')
    );

    var pagePosition = window.pageYOffset;

    if (pagePosition >= 1000) {
        for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(i) {
                box[i].style.opacity = "1";
            }, i * 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the function has to start if you scroll the page to the position 1000px and called in the body-tag:

Without the setTimeout it works, but with this function the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

I'm a beginner and want to understand JS, so please don't provide an answer using jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It appears your question can be answered here: [**JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Please let me know if it solves your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time your your timeout runs, the loop has finished processing, so `i` will always be the last iteration. You need a closure:

```
for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        box[index].style.opacity = "1";
    }, index*500);
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe -- It'll work..but I'll change it for clarity. Edit: Oh - the `timeout` function, yeah, that was wrong :D

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think a different variable name would make the operation clearer, but there's actually two `i` variables in tyme's original version - when it enters the function scope, it discards the outside `i` naming to just use `i` as a local argument.

Comment: Also worth noting that `i` would actually be one more than the number of items in the `box` array, which is what was causing the `undefined` error.

Comment: @Katana314 exactly, which would again have been `undefined` as it wouldn't be passed by the timeout

Comment: Why would `i` be one more? I thought `undefined` was coming from the `i` in the function being passed to the `timeout`

Comment: @tymeJV Ah yes, that too.  Without the `i` in the timeout function, it would be using the `i` from the outer scope, which the for loop would have incremented to beyond the end of the array, so `box[i]` would be undefined.  There's too much wrong here :)

Comment: Actually, Thorpe appears correct; I hadn't noticed `i` was being passed as an argument again inside the setTimeout scope. I was referring to the first function. The example looks fine now.

Comment: `i` would not increment beyond the array! The array length is `4` - `i` starts at `0` - up by `1` until not less than `4`. `4 < 4 == false`

Comment: If the length is 4, the highest index is 3, ie `box[0]` to `box[3]` are fine, but after the loop is finished (and by the time the timeout ran), `i` would be 4, and `box[4]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the scope. When anonymous function executes inside timeout `i` variable has the last value of the `i` in the iteration. There are two solutions:

1) Use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
      box[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }, i * 500);
  })(i);
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);//prints out 0 1 2 3 4
    }, i * 500)
  })(i);
}
```

2) Using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
 for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {

    setTimeout(function (i) {
        box[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }, i * 500);
}
```

```js
"use strict";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, i * 500)
}
```

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally
>   initializing it to a value.

Keep in mind `let` is feature fo ecmaScript 6.

Comment: Even if `set i` is an ES6 feature I haven't read yet, I think you linked to the wrong MDN article; it's detailing a `Set` object